# Using JUnit RunListener in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm working on project where I need to perform some action before running each JUnit test. This problem was solved using `RunListener` that could be added to the JUnit core. The project assembly is done using Maven, so I have this lines in my `pom` file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>cc.redberry.core.GlobalRunListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

So, everything works using:

```
mvn clean test
```

But when tests are started using IntelliJ (using its internal test runner) the actions coded in our `RunListener` are not executed, so it is impossible to perform testing using IntelliJ infrastructure.

As I see, IntelliJ does not parse this configuration from pom file, so is there a way to explicitly tell IntelliJ to add `RunListener` to JUnit core? May be using some VM options in configuration?

It is much more convenient to use beautiful IntelliJ testing environment instead of reading maven output.

P.S. The action I need to perform is basically a reset of static environment (some static fields in my classes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't see a way to specify a RunListener in Intellij, but another solution would be to write your own customer Runner and annotate @RunWith() on your tests.

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
        // run your code here. example:
        Runner.value = true;            

        super.runChild(method, notifier);
    }
}
```

Sample static variable:

```
public class Runner {
    public static boolean value = false;
}
```

Then run your tests like this:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class MyRunnerTest {
    @Test
    public void testRunChild() {
        Assert.assertTrue(Runner.value);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do your static initialization without a RunListener.

Comment: Thank you for another solution! I'm now thinking just to add one global parent for all my test classes with `@Before` method specified. So, in any case I'll have to edit all my test files.:( I'll create a ticket in IntelliJ bug tracker to add this feature.